# How to install reclaimed stone pathway without plastic edging?

Tags: outdoor, brick, landscaping

I;m installing a  3' wide path made out of reclaimed stones. Is there a proper way to install this path without using plastic edging on the sides of the path? These paths have been done before and all over the city of Cleveland. The finished product looks very similar to a cobblestone path [image]

Comment: Those are not cobblestones, but rather broken rock with sharp edges. If someone sold that to you as cobblestones I think you would have a case for getting your money back. It will not make a good walking surface for humans or for say dogs. Is the rock in place already? Cobblestones are rounded and make a much better walking surface although the famous Paris-Roubaix bicycle race over cobblestones is hard on the racers and their bicycles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Roubaix

Comment: If the crushed rock is in place perhaps it could be a *base* for a top surface of say pea gravel. Perhaps the crushed rock could be compacted first, but this rock might damage a roller or powered soil compactor. If you soaked the soil with a garden hose, it might press into the earth below.

Comment: Resist the temptation to use the metal edging to contain the rock and pea gravel. That metal edging is a source of severe injuries to dog's feet. http://www.aaha.org/blog/NewStat/post/2010/11/22/606169/Lawn-edging-a-danger-to-dogs.aspx

Comment: @Jim Stewart Yeah, I wasn't sure what to call them. They are salvaged stones. They're used all over the city of Cleveland as pathways. Even though they look rough, they look great once installed. I should have called them salvaged stones and not cobblestones.

Comment: Are these Cleveland pathways used by dog walkers? people in thinner soled shoes? Can you roll a stroller over them?

Comment: You can edit your original post.

Comment: @Jim Stewart. No the finished product is similar to cobblestones. Those aren't easy to roll a stroller over either. This application is for curbside landing. Will need  to worry about strollers or dog walkers.

Answer (score 1):

You can dig down an inch or so and "plant" the stones without using a container as such. If you dig a 3 foot wide area and place the stone pieces in the excavated area, the pristine earth/grass surrounding them will pretty much hold them in place.
Your success will vary based on the soil type and amount of water involved, etc. Sandy soil that gets a lot of rain, for example may not work as well as other conditions.